# IOS - Swift NSString

Tags: swift

Boas,

Estou a fazer uma aplicação onde vou medir o IMC dos utilizadores. 
Criei o *layout* mas no código estou a ter problemas.

Tenho um botão que ao deslizar muda o valor da altura ou peso.

```
var w:Float = 75

alturachg(_ sender:UISlider) {
h = sender.value
lblAltura.text = NSString(Format: " %2.f m", h) }
```

Antes de fechar `}` obriga-me a ter as String para não dar erro.

Comment: Você quer converter do tipo NSString para String? Se for isso basta fazer o seguinte: `NSString(Format: " %2.f m", h) as String`

Comment: `lblAltura.text = String(format: "%.2f m", sender.value)`

Answer (score 1):

A propriedade `value` do `UISlider` retorna um *float*.

Basta fazer um *cast* para `String`. Pode fazer algo semelhante a isso:

```
h = String(sender.value)
```